# Handling UITapGestureRecognizer in custom view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a custom view class. Inside my view controller I add a Tap gesture recognizer on this view object. Now, in the handler of tap gesture I am setting up a property on my view object which I am trying to fetch in the drawRect of my view class. Now, surprisingly when I print view objects in my "handleGesture" & "drawRect", I get two different objects. Because of this my if condition inside drawRect do not get execute. What could be the reason?

It do not come in state UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan. It always coming inside UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded.

```
// Adding Gesture in my view
 MyCustomView *customView= [[[MyCustomView alloc] init] autorelease];
UIGestureRecognizer *GestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
        [customView addGestureRecognizer:GestureRecognizer];
        [GestureRecognizer release];

// Handling tap on my view
- (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)GestureRecognizer; {
    MyCustomView *aView= (MyCustomView *)GestureRecognizer.view;
switch (iGestureRecognizer.state) {
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
        NSLog(@"Began");
        [aView setNeedsDisplay];
        aView.touchDown = YES;
        break;
    case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:    
        NSLog(@"Ended");
        aView.touchDown = NO;
        [aView setNeedsDisplay];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
}

// Inside my view class
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)iRect {
    if (self.touchDown) {
// Do something here
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing calling the drawRect method. You don't want to do this directly, but in your handleGesture method, you could put in a call to [aView setNeedsDisplay] and your view's drawRect will get called in the next drawing cycle.

Comment: If you wanted to do a bit of refactoring, you could have your custom view create its own gesture recognizer and implementation of handleGesture. That way it could handle all of this logic internally to the view and you might not need the touchDown flag you're using. Perhaps you could even eliminate the need to override drawRect:

Comment: Yeah... I thought so & tried that but thats not helping. Reason for this is I am redrawing my table inside my "handleGesture" which creates another object of my custom view & then it all messes up.

Comment: Ah, all the more reason to more the gesture recognition from the controller to the view. No doubt in any case, you should not be creating additional instances of the custom view.

Comment: There is some logic that needs to be handled in my view controller as a tap not only drives how my view look it also controls the data to be displayed. So, I am thinking of creating an mutable dictionary of custom view objects & fetch them from there instead of creating new ones.